# IE doesnot display an image in FLOAT left class.. Works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

my problem is in IE (version 11 and also some older one on Vista).. The page holzhandel.cz doesnot display an image in IE (does in chrome and fox). It is very simple page, the class has just float left and simple img tag.

(css file)

```
.pic img{
    height: 600px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

(code)

```
<div id="lg-5">< /div>
<div id="lg-3" class="pic">
<img src="images/1.jpg">
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the `.pic` class, because you're using a css3 property `display: initial;`, which is not supported in IE.

More exactly, in the stylesheet `formate.css`, line `390` has the  the following rule:

```
.pic {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, at line `395`, this rule is overwritten in a media query, by:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .pic {
        display: initial;
    }
}
```

which is not supported in IE and other CSS3 non-compliant browsers.

So my suggestion is to use `display: block;`, like this:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .pic{
        display: block;
    }
    ....
}
```

You can read more info about this css `display: initial;` property here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial